# @material-ui/styles Adapting the hook API

Tags: material-ui

After going through the document of @material-ui I got stuck in the @material-ui/styles section with some question wanting to ask?

- Which one of these 3 (Higher-order component, Styled components or Hook) is the best in practice to implement with React. Should I use Hook API from Material-UI with React Hook to have best result when styling with Material-UI? Because I'm currently adopting Hook in React.
- I came across these few line of codes and can't understand, please help me with syntax. This can found in the Adapting the hook API

̣̣(https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-the-hook-api)

```
function MyButton(props) {
  const { color, ...other } = props;
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return <Button className={classes.root} {...other} />;
}
```

What will `...other` be? And then why it is in the `<Button/>`?

Best Regards,

Comment: As for the 2nd question, `other` just stands for any other styles you want to take out of props. The example they're showing is only for `color` style property, but you extract more from the props object. This means the word "other" shouldn't really be there, you gotta swap it with the styles / properties you want to pull out of the props object or with nothing at all. 
As for the first question I'd leave it for someone else with more experience to answer, although im pretty sure those 3 can come hand-in-hand and are not contradicting each other.

Comment: Thanks so much Gibor, so 'other' here is just a spread for assign the rest of style/pros right?

Comment: exactly as you said :)